# how to add excludeMethods parameter list for custom interceptor in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

How can I add `excludeMethods` parameter list for my custom interceptor in `struts.xml` file.
`workflow` and `validation` interceptor have this parameter i.e `excludeMethods` through witch the `workflow` interceptor will not fire for excluded methods as described like this:

```
<action name="action" class="abc.ActionClass">
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
<param name="workflow.excludeMethods">doSomething</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result>Success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This I know. What I want to know is how can I do the same for my custom interceptor. I tried but failed. Here is my code:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:url action="go2"  method="forGo2" var="v_go2"/>
<a href="<s:property value='#v_go2'/>">HIT to check if excludeMethods parameter working or NOT.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="abc" extends="struts-default">

<interceptors>

<interceptor name="cust_intrcptr" class="pack.MyInterceptor2">
<param name="excludeMethods">forGo2</param> <!-- parameter for excluded method -->
</interceptor>

<interceptor-stack name="mystack2">
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
<interceptor-ref name="cust_intrcptr"/>
</interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>

<action name="go2" class="pack.GoAction" method="forGo2">
<interceptor-ref name="mystack2"/>
<result name="success">/welcome2.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**custom-interceptor**

```
package pack;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class MyInterceptor2 implements Interceptor{

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("#####Inside Interceptor#####");
      ai.invoke();
    }

}
```

**Action Class**

```
package pack;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class GoAction extends ActionSupport{
    public String forGo2(){
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Output generated without any errors. But in console output I am viewing "`#####Inside Interceptor#####`" that I did not expected because I excluded the interceptor for `forGo2` method. How can I exclude this interceptor for any given method in this case like `forGo2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific base class for this: [`MethodFilterInterceptor`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/MethodFilterInterceptor.html). From the Documentation:

> An abstract Interceptor that is applied to selectively according to
>   specified included/excluded method lists.

To use, first extend it in your interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor2 extends MethodFilterInterceptor {
```

Now, instead of overriding the `intercept` method, override `doIntercept`:

```
@Override
public String doIntercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("#####Inside Interceptor#####");
  ai.invoke();
}
```

The base class will handle `excludeMethods` automatically and invoke `doIntercept` as required.