# Struts2 Custom Interceptor with includeMethods

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

i written my own interceptor in Struts2 and configured in where ever i need in xml files and it is working fine till now.I have another requirement like it should be call only for some methods.So what i have to do please help.I gone through this below url [how to add excludeMethods parameter list for custom interceptor in struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828861/how-to-add-excludemethods-parameter-list-for-custom-interceptor-in-struts2) but no result.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issues by going through below links
http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/TokenSessionStoreInterceptor.html

http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/MethodFilterInterceptor.html#MethodFilterInterceptor%28%29

Comment: plus 1 for answering yourself without noone asking for it